# stylesheet_link_tag doesn't work, wrong directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on the stylesheet in Ruby on Rails tutorial today and as it says, I added

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %> 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>
```

which should read screen.css and print.css from public/stylesheets/blueprint folder.

However, when I opened up the browser, the style does not change so I inspected the html code and it shows

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/blueprint/screen.css></link>
```

Can anyone tell me why the route is wrong? Shouldn't it be public/stylesheets instead of /assets/somewhere?

Comment: I think you misfigure something between rails 3 (you're using) and a previous version of rails.

Comment: how should I fix it? which file tells it the route for stylesheet_link_tag?

Comment: See the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html you can either use the rails asset pipeline (default), or disable it and use the public directory

Comment: put your stylesheets in /app/assets/stylesheets and it will find automatically your stylesheets.

Comment: @house9 So what I understand is, if I'm using pipeline, it goes directly to asset folder; otherwise it looks up in the public folder? Right? Just to make it clear.

Comment: Exactly, check the manifest file in assets stylesheets - also when deploying you willl need to precompile

Comment: what is precompile? I don't remember having anything to compile in Ruby on Rails tutorial. And I couldn't find any file called manifest.

Answer (score 1):

As house9 said on comments, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html a 10 minutes reading.

--- answer to question in comments---
It will first check on /public folder, then it will try to find on assets folder. This behavior is valid for development.

In production all assets will be compiled and placed on public (default).

So, make sure you dont have files with the desired name in public and place it on assets.
Your application.css should have the sprockets notation :  `*= require_tree .` this will ensure that all valid files in this folder will be included on css.

If you're not using sprockets, make sure to import the desired files on application.css

Comment: what is a sprocket? and what does that notation do?